# C++ type casting vector class

Tags: c++, casting, types, vector

I have two vector classes:

```
typedef struct D3DXVECTOR3 {
    FLOAT x;
    FLOAT y;
    FLOAT z;
} D3DXVECTOR3, *LPD3DXVECTOR3;
```

and

```
class MyVector3{
    FLOAT x;
    FLOAT y;
    FLOAT z;
};
```

and a function:

```
void function(D3DXVECTOR3* Vector);
```

How is it possible (if it's possible) to achieve something like this:

```
MyVector3 vTest;
function(&vTest);
```

Comment: What's the real problem being solved - why do you need two seemingly identical classes?

Comment: The author might wan't to use a utility function from D3DX on his or her own Vector class but don't want to create a dependency to D3DXVECTOR3.

Comment: Still he would have a dependency on that function. So I see no benefits.

Comment: It might be in another file (not MyVector3.h/cpp) so you don't create a direct dependency from MyVector3 to D3DXVECTOR3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function(reinterpret_cast<D3DXVECTOR3*>(&vTest));
```

Generally speaking you should avoid `reinterpret_cast` though.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want a wrapper class for D3DXVECTOR3. In this case just inherit MyVector3 from it. Then you can pass MyVector3* anywhere you could earlier pass D3DXVECTOR3*.

Answer (score 1):

old c-style cast

```
MyVector3 vTest;
function((D3DXVECTOR3*)&vTest);
```